# glassfish 4 cluster jdbc connection pool not being installed on instances

Tags: glassfish

I might be missing something, but I created a JDBC mysql connection pool on the DAS and then created a resource and it says enabled on the two instances on different hosts.  I do not see the connections being added to the mysql server and it is is not throwing any errors except on null in the result set from the JSF page.  I have no other errors.  I also deleted the connection pool and resource and added using asadmin.  Asadmin says it installed on the two clients but no connections.  I also added mysql connector jar to the domain1/lib and see it on the nodes under the lib.

Comment: I setup glassfish 3.1.2.2 and install the application.  Setup the jdbc pool settings in the DAS and the nodes connect to the DB fine.  Is there something I am missing with Glassfish 4 for jdbc connections?

Comment: Have you ever managed to overcome this problem? I have the same issue now, too
The datasource is found per JNDI lookup (with @Resource Annotation)
But the underlying Connectionpool cannot be found

Comment: The OP hasn't been around since Jan 26, there's almost no chance he'll see this.